# composer dump-autoload and dynamic classes

Tags: php, composer-php

Let's say we have a file `lib/internal/Foo.php` with a class `Foo` in it.

composer.json adjusted accordingly:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "lib/internal/"
        ]
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected, class Foo is being found and included correctly.

Now, let's change a bit the file:

```
<?php
eval( base64_decode('Y2xhc3MgRm9ve30=') );

// 'Y2xhc3MgRm9ve30=' is just a string 'class Foo{}' encoded with base64
```

Everything still works as expected.

Now we want to boost autoloader and run composer dump-autoload command:

`composer dump-autoload --no-dev --classmap-authoritative`

Apparently, class Foo cannot be found, because it does not exist in `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`
Composer scans the file Foo.php, but cannot find a class and does not put it to the class mapping.

Is there any solution here?

For example, to extend a mapping somehow in composer.json, like:
`'Foo' => 'lib/internal/Foo.php'`
which will be accepted no matter, whether class statically exists or not.

PS. this is real project issue where I have some files encrypted for licensing purpose.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md#optimization-level-2-a-authoritative-class-maps: see "Trade-offs". You'll most likely have to ditch the `--classmap-authoritative` optimization if you want this to still work.

Comment: PSR-0 has been [deprecated](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) since 2014. Go for [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) instead.

Comment: Why not add all cleartext class and file names? You're welcome to provide your own autoloader if that is not an option, and this autoloader could also be "encrypted"

Answer (score 0):

You could include a default class declaration inside the file such as:

```
<?php

if (!isset($dynamicClass)) {
    class defaultFoo {}
} else {
    eval( base64_decode($dynamicClass) ); // 'Y2xhc3MgRm9ve30='
}
```

There's similar solutions in projects such as Magento 1.9 where local classes could look similar to this, in order to resolve multiple overrides from shared modules:

```
<?php

if (Module::isActive('KnownModule')) {
    class BaseEntity extends \Library\KnownModule\Entity {}
} else {
    class BaseEntity extends \Core\Data\Entity {}
}

class localEntity extends BaseEntity {
   // ...
}
```